# Can't sql connect to mysql database in nginx (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following sqlconnection.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword', 'mydb');

if ($mysqli->connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_rror() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

with **myuser**, **mypassword** and **mydb** values being set correctly.
Anyway, although I am able to do operations with phpmyadmin (I got that installed aswell) I can't get to connect to the database. Any idea on why and what exactly I should put in localhost?

Comment: No error message, no help.

Comment: @DaSourcerer exactly, "no error message" at all... the website dies but no error is displayed.

Comment: Then surely there's something in the logs?

Comment: I'm surprised you're not seeing a string of errors here. Perhaps you should take a look in your server logs. For a start, you should be checking `$mysqli->connect_error`. Note: it's not a function.

Comment: "*Any idea on why and what exactly I should put in localhost?*" - it should be the hostname or IP address of the MySQL server; if (as is often the case) that is the same machine as the web server, one can usually state `localhost` (and the driver will then connect over a socket in Unix or named pipe in Windows).

Answer (score -1):

Just try this way~

```
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'dbname';

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

if all your db information is correct, should be working

Comment: This may or may not work, but you've suggested using `mysql_*()` functions which are deprecated and support will be removed. The OP is already using the newer `mysqli_*()` functions, so any answer really should follow suit.